# [Gstreamer: Got EOS from element "pipeline0"]

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, orange-pi

I am newbie to gstreamer handling. I am following Gstreamer tutorial to set up Gstreamer on Orangepi Zero development kit. I am trying to run the video streaming via Gstreamer, but it throws me a error as follows:

media: Wildlife.mp4

Command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location= /home/ash/Videos/Wildlife.mp4 ! videorate ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! autovideosink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...

Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0: 

Failed to connect to X display server

Additional debug info:

gstglimagesink.c(833): _ensure_gl_setup (): /GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-
actual-sink-glimage/GstGLImageSink:sink

Pipeline is PREROLLED ...

Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...

New clock: GstSystemClock

**Got EOS from element "pipeline0".**

Execution ended after 0:00:00.000987695

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...

Setting pipeline to READY ...

Setting pipeline to NULL ...

Freeing pipeline ...
```

Also when I try to play media: "Wildlife.ogv"

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location= /home/ash/Videos/Wildlife.ogv ! videorate ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! autovideosink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...

Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0: 

Failed to connect to X display server

Additional debug info:

gstglimagesink.c(833): _ensure_gl_setup (): /GstGLImageSinkBin:autovideosink0-actual-sink-glimage/GstGLImageSink:sink

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data flow error.

Additional debug info:

gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:

streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.

Setting pipeline to NULL ...

Freeing pipeline ...
```

Two different errors while running two different video formats.

Please suggest the solution. Thanks

Comment: Try using `GST_DEBUG` for more logs. eg. `GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch-1.0 <your pipeline >`

Comment: Hi, are you running the code in an ssh connection. Seems like it cannot connect to X display server.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler: yes I am running in in SSH connection. even if i am sinking it with "tcpserversink host= ip address port=5000" and check on vlc network...its shows the same error and nothing plays on vlc.

Comment: @vk_gst: I will try this to check more logs details.....thanks

Comment: Oh I see, you can use autovideosink for local display only (and it cannot display jpeg encoded images). One more thing that I see is  you are not decoding the video file. You probably need a `decodebin` element between your `filesrc` and `videorate` elements.

Comment: @vk_gst :
0:00:00.330097223 22040  0x13aaba0 ERROR              gldisplay gstgldisplay_x11.c:88:gst_gl_display_x11_new: Failed to open X11 display connection with name, '(null)'
gstwaylandsink.c:289:gst_wayland_sink_find_display:<autovideosink0-actual-sink-wayland> warning: Failed to create GstWlDisplay: 'Failed to connect to the wayland display '(default)''
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.339700199 22040  0x13aa090 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2396:gst_base_src_update_length:<filesrc0> processing at or past EOS

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler; hi, i tried with what you suggested but it also shows some errors like Stream contains no data....etc. also i can not send you the error results since the reply comment box has character limitation. Could you please tell me how can i send you the error log in case. Thanks.

Comment: @Emlinux you can use https://gist.github.com/ to share your log

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler: I created gist; please check. Thanks